# Cannot install Rust on RHEL 6.10 using curl

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to install rust 1.48 on RHEL 6.10 using curl and getting following error

```
info: downloading installer
Cannot execute /tmp/tmp.ShsTMGuMqK/rustup-init (likely because of mounting /tmp as noexec).
Please copy the file to a location where you can execute binaries and run ./rustup-init.
```

Here are my commands to install rust

```
curl --insecure -sSf -o $HOME/rust/rustup-init https://sh.rustup.rs
chmod +x $HOME/rust/rustup-init
./$HOME/rust/rustup-init -s -y --default-toolchain 1.48
```

I find out this https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39771 but it did not worked. My $HOME directory has write permission as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message seems clear but you seem to be misunderstanding it: `sh.rustup.sh` *downloads* rustup-init (to `$TMP`) then executes it. On your system it can't execute it because your TMP is mounted noexec.

downloading `sh.rustup.sh` under a different name doesn't change the content of the script, it's still going to download the actual `rustup-init` and try to run it, which will fail again.

What you should do is *exactly what the error message tells you*: move/copy `/tmp/tmp.ShsTMGuMqK/rustup-init` (the rustup-init it downloaded) to your home then run that.

Comment: But problem is sh.rustup.sh download rustup-init to /tmp and execute together. So i cannot copy it before execution

Comment: I don't really see how that's an issue unless you're doing completely unattended installations? And if you are you could [just download the correct installer for the platform](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/other.html).

Comment: I was using ansible to install. So installer helped

Comment: I like this answer but unfortunately not the best as I need unattended way. By the way you can just navigate the file in the tmp, copy it.. I need to find a way how to automatically do that in bash script.

Comment: @MaXi32 see the latter comment, if you're doing an unattended installation you can download the correct installer (rustup-init) directly and run that, you don't have to go through rustup's script.

Comment: @Masklinn ok i missed that one. I did not read comment as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer @Masklinn, if you have secured tmp you can use this 2 lines to install rustup-init unattended way (no question should be asked):

```
sce=$(curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s 2>&1 | grep 'because of mounting \/tmp' | awk '{ print $3 }') | cp "${sce}" ~/rustup-init
     
~/./rustup-init -y
```